# How to filter a persistent map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a persistent map which I want to filter. Something like this:

```
(filter #(-> % val (= 1)) {:a 1 :b 1 :c 2})
```

The above comes out as `([:a 1] [:b 1])` (a lazy sequence of map entries). However I want to be get `{:a 1 :b 1}`.

How can I filter a map so it remains a map without having to rebuild it from a sequence of map entries?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

And another one:

```
(let [m {:a 1 :b 2 :c 1}]
  (select-keys m (for [[k v] m :when (= v 1)] k)))
```

Answer (score 21):

```
(into {} (filter #(-> % val (= 1)) {:a 1 :b 1 :c 2}))
```

Of course this *does* rebuild the map from a sequence of map entries, but there is no way around it. If you're going to filter the entries by value, you're going to have to go through them one by one to see which values match your predicate and which don't.

Updated (see comments below):

With the newly introduced `keep` function, the source of which you can see [here](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/7b4b8e18c0d28e03e7c66f54bc441ef355ceb5ed/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5155) (should work just fine in Clojure 1.1 if you want to backport), this seems like a nice way to go about it *if you don't use `nil` as a key*:

```
(let [m {:a 1 :b 1 :c 2}]
  (apply dissoc m (keep #(-> % val (= 1) (if nil (key %))) m)))
; => {:a 1, :b 1}
```

Also, if you do actually see a slowdown related to rebuilding your map, you can use a transient map at the rebuilding step:

```
(persistent! (loop [m (transient {})
                    to-go (seq [[:a 1] [:b 2]])]
               (if to-go
                 (recur (apply assoc! m (first to-go))
                        (next to-go))
                 m)))
; => {:a 1, :b 2}
```

Comment: Well, *theoretically* you could have it filtered by value without rebuilding by returning a map with dissoc-ed keys that correspond to non-matching values. I was hoping there is a language-supported way to do it.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I'll add two ways to do it in a second, but note that you're not very likely to see a great gain in the performance department (unless you've got a really huge map and you'll only be dissocing a small number of keys).

Comment: Hm, actually it's not so much "two ways to do it" as "one way to do it and one way to worry less about rebuilding". Not that you're very likely to need to worry. :-)

Comment: into uses transient conj!, so I'm not sure there's a point in doing loop-recur

Answer (score 3):

Per your comment to Michał Marczyk:

```
(defn filter* [f map]
  (reduce (fn [m [k v :as x]]
            (if-not (f x)
              (dissoc m k)
              m))
          map map))

user> (filter* #(-> % val (= 1)) {:a 1 :b 1 :c 2})
{:a 1, :b 1}
```

I don't see that you're going to gain much with this vs. Michał's version.

Answer (score 3):

Need to traverse all entries, but can leverage Clojures persistent maps:

```
(apply dissoc my-map (for [[k v] my-map :when (not= v 1)] k))
```

Answer (score 3):

While `(into {} (filter some-fn some-map))` works, I want to point out that `into` also has a transducer arity since Clojure 1.7.0. I.e.

```clj
(into {} (filter some-fn) some-map)
```

I think this should be preferred since it improves reusability. E.g. you can do

```clj
(def only-ones (filter #(-> % val (= 1))))

(into {} only-ones {:a 1 :b 1 :c 2}) => {:a 1 :b 1}
```

Or to provide a more elaborate example:

```clj
(def remove-empty-vals (remove (comp empty? val)))

(into {} (comp cat remove-empty-vals (replace {[:b "non"] [:b "non-empty"]}))
      [{:a "keep" :b nil :c "empty"} {:a "" :b "non" :c "first"} {:d "" :e "value"}])
=> {:a "keep", :c "first", :b "non-empty", :e "value"}
```

Comment: I think the transcucer arity is covered in Michał Marczyk's answer above

Comment: @philCooper It isn't, and it couldn't be in 2010 since transducers weren't introduced in Clojure yet.

Comment: apologies, you are very much correct.  I miscounted parens.  I guess I need rainbow parens as helpers to get it right

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one using `reduce-kv`

```
(defn filter-kv [pred map]
  (reduce-kv (fn [accumulator key value]
               (if (pred key value)
                 (assoc accumulator key value)
                 accumulator)) {} map))
```

Usage

```
(filter-kv (fn [key _]
             (not (= key "a"))) {"a" {:some "a"}
                                 "b" {:some "b"}
                                 "c" {:some "c"}})

>> {"b" {:some "b"}
    "c" {:some "c"}}
```

Comment: You can change `{}` at the end with `(empty map)` to make it more generic and work for any collection supporting `kv-reduce` protocol.

Comment: Also, this approach is more efficient when most keys will be removed, i.e. there will be a few `assoc`'s into a result map that starts with empty `{}`.

If there is an expectation that only a few keys will be removed, then it would be more efficient to start `accumulator` with the original `map` and reverse `if` to `dissoc` the filtered out keys.

Answer (score 1):

I tried myself on macro for this based on kotarak's version. Its my first macro doing something useful, so please bear with me and comments welcome.

```
(defmacro filter-map [bindings pred m]
  `(select-keys ~m
    (for [~bindings ~m
      :when ~pred]
      ~(first bindings)
    )
  )
)
```

Example

```
user=> (filter-map [key val] (even? (:attr val)) {:a {:attr 2} :b {:attr 3} :c {:attr 4}})
{:c {:attr 4}, :a {:attr 2}}
```